# How to setup a socket client with spring-integration?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

I'm using `spring 4` annotation based configuration, and would like to set up a simple telnet/socket client.

This is what I have so far:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class MySocket {
    @Bean
    public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean clientFactory() {
        TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fact = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
        fact.setType("client");
        fact.setHost(host);
        fact.setPort(port);
        fact.setUsingNio(true);
        fact.setSingleUse(true);
        fact.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        return fact;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel clientChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "clientChannel")
    public TcpOutboundGateway outGateway(TcpNioClientConnectionFactory factory, 
            @Qualifier("clientChannel") MessageChannel clientChannel) throws Exception {
        TcpOutboundGateway gate = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        gate.setConnectionFactory(factory);
        gate.setReplyChannel(clientChannel);
        return gate;
    }
}

@Component
public class MyMessageService {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("clientChannel")
  private MessageChannel clientChannel;

  public void run() {
    Message<String> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload("test").build();
    Message<?> rsp = new MessagingTemplate(clientChannel).sendAndReceive(msg);
  }
}
```

Result: `org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers`

What am I missing here to send the message via the socket and receive the reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `@MessageEndpoint` annotation, but you need a consumer on the channel...

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "clientChannel")
@Bean
public TcpOutboundGateway outGateway(AbstractClientConnectionFactory scf) {
    ...
}
```

The gateway needs a reference to the connection factory. Since you are using a factory bean, it's easiest to add it as a parameter to the bean's factory method.

Comment: You probably mean a `AbstractClientConnectionFactory` as scf parameter? Added the `TcpOutboundGateway` to my post above. But now getting the error: `Parameter 0 of method outGateway in MySocket required a bean of type 'org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection. AbstractClientConnectionFactory' that could not be found.` Is the `@ServiceActivator` correct on the Gateway?

Comment: Sorry; yes, I meant client. Yes, `@ServiceActivator` wraps the gateway in a consumer bean. I suggest you change the `clientFactory` bean to create a `TcpNioClientConnectionFactory` directly instead of using the FB.

Comment: If I do so, I'm still getting an error. Something must still be missing. The application startup error msg is (in short): `The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle: MyMessageService > MySocket > outGateway > clientChannel`.

Comment: Maybe it's not correct that I set the `InputChannel` to both the `@ServiceActivator` and as the `gate.replyChannel`?

Comment: Yes, that is really wrong. You reply to the `clientChannel` and at the same time listen on that channel via `@ServiceActivator`

Comment: Then where does the dependency cycle come from that prevents the app to start? Spring complains about `MyMessageService (field private clientChannel) > MySocket > clientChannel`. And moreover, if I remove any references to the injected channel in `MyMessageService`, then I'm getting again `MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers`. There must still be an error in the configuration above..

Comment: You ned to do as I suggested - the `clientChannel` is the input channel; leave the `replyChannel` unspecified, and the framework will send the reply to the messaging template. You only need a reply channel if you want to send the result somewhere else first (e.g. an `ObejctToStringTransformer` to convert the `byte[]` to `String`. And in that case, you would omit the output channel on the transformer.

Comment: Ok, omitting the `replyChannel` completely was the missing piece.